# C#: split file path

Tags: c#, split

first of all sorry about my english. I need to split a file path. For example:

```
"C:\Folder\Folder2\1.cr2"
```

I need to get file drive, file path, file name and file extension separately:

```
C:\ , 
Folder\Folder2 ,
1 and 
.cr2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any effort so far? You can easily find file name, extension name and root folder using `Path` class. Just use Google.

Comment: What searches have you done? This is pretty simple stuff. [Path.GetPathRoot(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx). [Path.GetExtension(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My problem is to find first and second. The FileName and FileExtension is not a problem. I can't find how I can split C:\ and the path without the filedrive

Comment: @user3284892 You can find `C:` with `GetPath`, you can find `1.cr2` with `GetFileName`, remove this strings from your original string. TA...TA...TAAAA, you have now `Folder\Folder2` (might need to remove some \ as well).

Comment: Show us something. Your code. Effort please.

Comment: @user3284892 . Thats what I was missing. Remove the information from the original string. I'm so dumb. Thanks.